# using of unique constraint making the user unable to login in symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I have used an unique constraint for the username in the registration form of the user.

User entity has following code

```
/*

* @UniqueEntity(fields="username",message="Username is already in use")
*/

class users

{

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="username should not be blank")
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=40)
     *
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="password should not be blank")
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=40)
     */
    private $password;
}
```

For registration every thing went fine with this entity when comes to login it is showing error username already in use.  Can we keep the unique constraint within controller i.e within form.so that only for registration form uniqueness is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Use validation groups:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/validation.html#validation-groups

(when you follow the link - you'll see very similar case: user and registration)

**edit**:

I assume that you have an "user_type" field in your user entity (for example possible values could be: "normal_user" and "affiliate"). If so, then you just need specify these two fields combination as a unique. Like this:

```
@UniqueEntity(fields={"username", "user_type"},message="Username is already in use") */
```

Comment: Thank you so much Cyprian  this link really helped me lot

Comment: sorry Cyprian i have stuck with another problem please help with this my unique entity is only working for only one table,i want it to work with all the tables,all the tables should have different values

Comment: sorry, I can't understand what you're asking for. What do you mean by that should work for all tables? Please, try rephrase your question (a punctuation will be very helpful as well ;) )

Comment: i have a user registration,affliate registration both store the values in two different tables.i have create unique entity for both user,affliate.so that it is not allowing the repeated usernames of that table.but affliate,user can register with same name

Comment: if you are not clear i will post my question please check it Cyprian

Comment: ya Cyprian i have but user_type for all the normal users is users only how can  it can be unique.it is the default value iam setting for users

Comment: ok, the question is: how do you distinguish regular users and affiliates based on data from users table?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30980/discussion-between-bhari-and-cyprian)